# Space Invaders - strange movement with alien movement algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm

I've been working for a while on a clone of space invaders. The biggest problem I've faced by far is getting the aliens to move. After a lot of effort, I've developed n algorithm to move them. The algorithm behaves as expected, except that when the aliens have finished moving to the left/right and then move down, the left or rightmost aliens begin to converge on the two next to them, overlapping their sprites. Monitoring their X coordinates, I discovered that they move 10 pixels to the left/right every time they move down. I can't figure out why they do this, and am hoping you can help me. Here is my movement algorithm (the aliens are arranged in 2 rows of 10 and this method is called every ten frames. `movestate` dictates which direction the aliens are moving in.):

```
public void alienMove()
    {
        boolean movedown = false;
        if(movestate)
        {
            for(int i = 0;i<aliens.length;i++)
            {
                if(aliens[i].getX()==950)
                {
                    movestate = false;
                    movedown = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    aliens[i].setX(aliens[i].getX()+10);
                }
            }
            if(movedown)
            {
                for(int j = 0;j<aliens.length;j++)
                {
                    aliens[j].setY(aliens[j].getY()+20);
                }
                movedown = false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for(int i = 0;i<aliens.length;i++)
            {
                if(aliens[i].getX()==50)
                {
                    movestate = true;
                    movedown = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    aliens[i].setX(aliens[i].getX()-10);
                }
            }
            if(movedown)
            {
                for(int j = 0;j<aliens.length;j++)
                {
                    aliens[j].setY(aliens[j].getY()+20);
                }
                movedown = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Seems like a great case for a debugger, have you tried debugging?

Comment: Shouldn't you swap `movestate` *after* you have moved down? Also, the aliens are not moving as a block, because you test the x position for each individual alien; maybe you should determine `movedown` outside the block, bease on the position of the top left alien, say.

Comment: @RyPope As a matter of fact I have. I came here simply because I couldn't work out what was happening. I apologize for my obvious ignorance, but I was under the impression that SO was a place where one could get help, rather than be insulted. My mistake

Comment: @imulsion Oh come on now, surely you don't get insulted just by someone asking if you've debugged...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the aliens are about to hit the right edge. The first 9 (reading left-to-right) don't have X = 950, so move 10 pixels right. Then the rightmost does have X=950, so *doesn't* move right; instead, it triggers the direction change and downshift.

Similarly, at the left edge, the first alien doesn't move, but triggers the (later) downshift and direction reversal, then the other nine aliens move left by 10 pixels.

You need to treat all the aliens the same way. Either move the edge alien as well, or don't move any aliens when the edge is reached.

Comment: I can't thank you enough. Thanks so much for actually making me understand the problem I had.

Answer (score 0):

Before trying to debug this code, I would propose you to improve and simplify it. First, if you look at your code, there are many parts completely similar that could be easily factorized.

Plus, you may be more comfortable if you had an `enum Direction` with some methods like `move(Point p)`, the code would be clearer. Plus, I get that `aliens[i].getX() == 50` is actually always `false` except for the leftmost alien, so this test should be out of the loop.

It may also be the reason why your code doesn't work, because your first loop moves the aliens from `aliens[0]` to `aliens[aliens.length - 1]`. Only the last alien can verify `aliens[i].getX() == 950` so when this condition is reached, **all the aliens from `aliens[0]` to `aliens[aliens.length - 2]` will be moved to the right and to the bottom, whereas `aliens[aliens.length - 1]` will only be moved to the bottom**.

Answer (score 0):

Normally in Space Invaders, the aliens move as a block.  So when they are moving left, you wouldn't want to test that all of them have reached coordinate 50. Just the leftmost one.  So perhaps:

```
if(aliens[i].getX()==50)
```

should be:

```
if(aliens[0].getX()==50)
```

etc.  And correspondingly:

```
if(aliens[aliens.length - 1].getX()==950)
```

when they are going right?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bug, last one didn't move, but all before it has moved in left/right direction;

```
if(aliens[i].getX()==950)
{
   movestate = false;
   movedown = true;
}
else
{
   aliens[i].setX(aliens[i].getX()+10);
}
```

this check `if(aliens[i].getX()==950)` should be after increment.
In last iteration you have moved all aliens to left/right but last one detects edge and its position it isn't moved, so all movement effect from last iteration should be reverted.