# Space Invader Recreation: Aliens continue to move laterally when moving downward

Tags: java, animation, repaint

For a programming class I have to recreate the game Space Invaders in java. I've gotten pretty far and am actually almost finished however there is an issue when my squadron of aliens drop a level. Interestingly enough it occurs in the top two columns of my aliens 2D array. When the squadron drops as a group the first time the entire top row shifts to the right and the very first alien of the 2nd row shifts to the left. In all of the subsequent drops it is only the first alien of the 2nd row that continues to move farther and farther to left. Initially I wrote the code so that the x and y position of each alien changes first and then I call the repaint method. Thinking that this was the issue I removed the changing of the y position outside of the double for loops. So now the x position changes for each alien and the screen is repainted so it shifts left or right. Then if the drop ready boolean (within the double for loops) was set to true then the y position of each alien is shifted down and the screen is repainted again. So there is a separate repaint() call for each type of change. This hasn't helped either though and I am at my wits end. My code for both the Alien class and Squadron class is listed below. Does anyone know why this may be happening?

Alien Class:

```
public class Alien extends Invader{
    private int alienType;//denotes the type of alien
    private GamePanel gamePanel;
private Rectangle rectangle;//used to set bounds of each alien for collision

public Alien(int xLoc, int yLoc, GamePanel gp){
    this();
    gamePanel=gp;
    rectangle = new Rectangle();
    alienType=0;
}
public Alien(){
    alienType = 0;
    rectangle = new Rectangle();
    //inherited properties
    this.setSpeed(10);//number of pixels aliens move
    this.setHeight(20);
    this.setWidth(20);
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setColor(Color.white);
    this.setDirection(Direction.East);//initial direction
}
//moves the alien left
public void moveLeft(){
    getLocation().x += getSpeed();
}
//moves the alien right
public void moveRight(){
    getLocation().x -= getSpeed();
}
//moves the alien downward
public void moveDown(){
    getLocation().y += 2*getSpeed();
    //resets their direction
    if(getDirection()==Direction.East)
        setDirection(Direction.West);
    else
        setDirection(Direction.East);
}
//draws the different type of aliens
@Override
public void draw(Graphics g){
    getRectangle().setBounds(getLocation().x, getLocation().y, getWidth(), getHeight());//setting bounds of rectangle to dimensions of alien
    //determines visiblity of aliens
    if(isVisible()){
        g.setColor(getColor());
        switch(getAlienType()){
            case 1:
                //type 1 alien is a circle with two smaller circles under it
                g.fillOval(getLocation().x, getLocation().y, getWidth(), getHeight());
                g.fillOval(getLocation().x, getLocation().y+getHeight(), getWidth()/2, getHeight()/2);
                g.fillOval(getLocation().x + (getWidth()-getWidth()/2), getLocation().y+getHeight(), getWidth()/2, getHeight()/2);
                break;
            case 2:
                //type 2 alien is a square with two oval on the bottom
                g.fillRect(getLocation().x, getLocation().y, getWidth(), getHeight());
                g.fillOval(getLocation().x, getLocation().y+getHeight(), getWidth(), getHeight()/4);
                g.fillOval(getLocation().x+(getWidth()/2), getLocation().y+getHeight()+(getHeight()/4), getWidth()/2, getHeight()/4);
                break;
            case 3:
                //type 3 alien is a triangle with a circle on top
                Polygon triangle = new Polygon();
                triangle.addPoint(getLocation().x+(getWidth()/2), getLocation().y+5);
                triangle.addPoint(getLocation().x,getLocation().y+getHeight());
                triangle.addPoint(getLocation().x+getWidth(), getLocation().y+getHeight());
                g.fillPolygon(triangle);
                g.drawOval(getLocation().x +(getWidth()/2), getLocation().y-5, getWidth()/2, getHeight()/2);
        }
    }
}
    //mutator and accessor methods
}
```

Squadron Class:

```
public class Squadron implements ActionListener{

private Alien[][] aliens = new Alien[5][12];//2D array of invading aliens
private Timer moveTimer;//controls movement of squadron
private int numVisible;//current number of aliens that have not been destroyed
private int moveCount;//denotes the number of squad moves
private GamePanel gamePanel;
private boolean dropReady;//determines if squadron is ready to drop

public Squadron(GamePanel gp){
    dropReady = false;
    moveCount=0;
    //initializes all aliens
   for(int i=0; i<aliens.length; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<aliens[i].length; j++){
                aliens[i][j] = new Alien(0, 0, gp);
                //sets location based on position in the array
                aliens[i][j].getLocation().x = (j*2) * (aliens[i][j].getWidth() + aliens[i][j].getWidth()/2);
                aliens[i][j].getLocation().y = (i*2) * ((aliens[i][j].getHeight() + aliens[i][j].getHeight()/2));
                aliens[i][j].getLocation().y+= gp.getHeight()/6;//shifts aliens downward away from spaceship
                //sets the type of alien based in row position
                if(i==0){
                    aliens[i][j].setAlienType(1);
                    aliens[i][j].setPointValue(40);
                }    
                else if(i>0 && i<3){
                    aliens[i][j].setAlienType(2);
                    aliens[i][j].setPointValue(20);
                }    
                else if(i>=3){
                    aliens[i][j].setAlienType(3);
                    aliens[i][j].setPointValue(10);
                }    
            }
        }
   moveTimer = new Timer(1000,this);
   numVisible = 60;//set to initial number of aliens
   gamePanel = gp;

   moveTimer.start();
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    if(gamePanel.isEnabled()){
        loop: for(int i=0; i<getAliens().length; i++){
                for(int j =0; j<getAliens()[i].length; j++){
                    //alien lateral and vertical movements are based on if any aliens in a given row/column are visible
                    //moves aliens to the east
                    if(getAliens()[i][j].getDirection() == Direction.East && !dropReady && aliens[i][j].isVisible()){
                        getAliens()[i][j].moveLeft();
                    }
                    //moves alien to the west
                    else if(getAliens()[i][j].getDirection() == Direction.West && !dropReady && aliens[i][j].isVisible()){
                        getAliens()[i][j].moveRight();
                    }
                    //moves alien down
                    if(getAliens()[i][j].getLocation().x>= getGamePanel().getWidth()-aliens[i][j].getWidth() || getAliens()[i][j].getLocation().x<0){
                        dropReady=true;
                    }
                    //stops when alien reaches the bottom
                    if(getAliens()[i][j].getLocation().y+getAliens()[i][j].getHeight() >= getGamePanel().getHeight()-gamePanel.getLaserCanon().getHeight()){
                        getMoveTimer().stop();
                        gamePanel.gameOver();
                    }
                }
            }
            moveCount++;
            getGamePanel().repaint();
            if(dropReady){
                drop();
                gamePanel.repaint();
            }
            //increases speed every 4 lateral moves
            if(moveCount%4==0){
                faster();
            }
    }    
}
//reduces delay time in order to increase speed
public void faster(){
   int delay = moveTimer.getDelay();
        delay -=25;
        if(delay>0)
        moveTimer.setDelay(delay); 
}
//calls move down method for each alien and resets dropReady flag
public void drop(){
    for(int i=0; i<aliens.length; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<aliens[i].length; j++){
            aliens[i][j].moveDown();
        }
    }
    dropReady=false;
}
//used when reset button is pressed. Sets aliens their initial position and redraws all aliens
public void resetPos(){
    for(int i=0; i<aliens.length; i++){
        for(int j=0;j<aliens[i].length; j++){
        aliens[i][j].getLocation().x = (j*2) * (aliens[i][j].getWidth() + aliens[i][j].getWidth()/2);
        aliens[i][j].getLocation().y = (i*2) * ((aliens[i][j].getHeight() + aliens[i][j].getHeight()/2));
        aliens[i][j].getLocation().y+= gamePanel.getHeight()/6;
        aliens[i][j].setVisible(true);
        }
    }  
    gamePanel.repaint();
}
//mutator and accessor methods

}
```

I realize that another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25911968/space-invaders-strange-movement-with-alien-movement-algorithm) similar to mine has been asked but in reading it over I feel that I've implemented their suggestions to no avail, so something else must be causing the problem. Any help is appreciated

Comment: I find it too difficult to check your current posted code, I suppose there are more classes involved in the game, and it's not easy to see what's going on at first glance. As a small tip, I would suggest you to check every point in your code where you move alliens laterally. Then debug the code and see where are they getting called from.

Comment: I have been doing that and haven't noticed anything yet. I'll give it another shot and try to look more carefully. But the only other self made class is GamePanel which is a JPanel that holds all of the game objects like the spaceship, aliens, the canon at the bottom etc. The paintComponent() method is within that class.